# how to Access to the Response body in the retrofit?

Tags: android, api, service, request, retrofit

I changed the Volley library to Retrofit. Now I want to access the response body like the Volley library. I searched the internet and came up with this solution, but when I run the program, the program closes and shows a low error. Thank you in advance for your help.

---

### apiService Class

```
   public void getVerifyCode(String mobile, RequestStatus requestStatus) {
    Log.i(TAG, "getVerifyCode: Called");

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("command", "register_user");
    jsonObject.addProperty("mobile", mobile);

    Log.i(TAG, "getVerifyCode: requestCode: " + jsonObject.toString());
    retrofitApi.getVerifyCode(jsonObject).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.i(TAG, "getVerifyCode:onResponse: " + response.toString());
            requestStatus.onSuccess(response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getVerifyCode:onFailure= " + t.getMessage());
            requestStatus.onError(new Exception(t));
        }
    });
}
```

---

### Retrofit Callback

```
@POST(".")
Call<ResponseBody> getVerifyCode(@Body JsonObject body);
```

---

### Logcat

```
I/ApiService: getVerifyCode: Called
I/ApiService: getVerifyCode: requestCode: {"command":"register_user","mobile":"0915*******7"}
I/ApiService: getVerifyCode:onResponse: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://**********ion.freehost.io/}
W/System.err: at ir.*****pp.*****k.ApiService$2.onResponse(ApiService.java:75)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *Finally, with these changes, I was able to reach a conclusion.*

**ApiSeviceClass**

```
  public void getVerifyCode(String mobile, RequestStatus requestStatus) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getVerifyCode: Called");

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("command", "register_user");
        map.put("mobile", mobile);

        Log.i(TAG, "getVerifyCode: requestCode: " + map.toString());

        retrofitApi.callBack(map).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String strResponseBody = response.body().string();
                        Log.i(TAG, "getVerifyCode:onResponse: " + strResponseBody);
                        requestStatus.onSuccess(strResponseBody);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getVerifyCode:onFailure= " + t.getMessage());
                requestStatus.onError(new Exception(t));
            }
        });
    }
```

---

**Retrofit Callback**

```
 @POST(".")
    Call<ResponseBody> callBack(@QueryMap Map<String, String> map);
```

Answer (score 2):

enqueue callback method onResponse's `response.body()` is ResponseBody.

In my opinion, I recommend using Gson or Moshi to add it to Retrofit.
Then you don't always have to translate using JsonObject like that.

In addition, if you add `suspend` to the head of the function of the api service interface you created, you can return a `Response` or the `model` itself without enqueue in the **coroutine**. (Retrofit automatically handles it in a background thread, so Coroutine does not need to be handled in a scope other than the UI.)
Also, Response object supports ErrorBody, ResultCode, etc.